# How to make all the posts commentable by default? Imputs in Settings/Discussions are not saved

Tags: comments, quick-edit

I've modified my website quite a bit and now looks almost as I desire.
I've set all the posts to be commentable in Settings/Discussions but it seems that this imput is not saved and new posts by authors are not commentable.
Everytime, I need to "quick edit" the new post and mark the |_|Allow Comments field as selected |x|.
This takes me a lot of time and I wonder if there's a way to have a function to make all the new posts as commentable as, just like I said, it seems not possible to choose it as option in Settings/Discussions.

Thanks!

Comment: Something is broken if your global comments are not being saved. Does it work when using a standard theme (twentysomething)?

Comment: You could try adding `add_filter('comments_open', '__return_true');` in your `functions.php` file.

Comment: Birgire, you're correct! Do you want to add it as an answer so that I can vote for it?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common method to keep all the posts open for comments, is to add this line into the file `functions.php` in the current theme directory :

```
add_filter('comments_open', '__return_true');
```

where `__return_true` is just a core function that always returns `true`.

ps: since this seems to be helpful, regarding to the problem described by @user27309, it's better to have the comment solution, added as an answer ;-)